# Safe removal of "unused" runtime dependencies

Tags: java, maven, apache-camel

I have a Java project managed by Maven deployed to Glassfish.

My question is, how can I safely remove maven-managed dependencies that may be runtime dependencies?

I've used the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) to identify unused dependencies on a legacy project:

```
mvn dependency:analyze -DignoreNonCompile=true
```

The output looks like this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze (default-cli) @ MyProject ---
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[WARNING]    commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.3:compile
[WARNING]    junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[WARNING]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.3:compile
[WARNING]    ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-base:jar:2.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:9.5.1-5:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-mina2:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-spring-ws:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-saxon:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-servlet:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-hl7:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-velocity:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.apache.camel:camel-ejb:jar:2.15.3:compile
[WARNING]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
```

I'd like to remove these "unused" dependencies, but I'm worried about the application failing at runtime.

The [ignoreNonCompile](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#ignoreNonCompile) option I enabled promises to "Ignore Runtime/Provided/Test/System scopes for unused dependency analysis", but as far as I know setting the scope of a dependency is something a developer does (it doesn't happen automatically), and so I don't think I can be certain that these "unused" dependencies aren't actually runtime dependencies.

The reason I've tagged this question `apache-camel` in specific is because I worry that the maven dependency plugin is especially likely to mis-identify "unused" Camel dependencies because of the Camel DSL. For example, the `camel-ftp` component is used by a DSL that looks like this:

```
from("ftp://foo@myserver?password=secret&ftpClient.dataTimeout=30000").to("bean:foo");
```

I think that as far as Maven is concerned this is just a String, so it may not realize that the project has a real dependency on the [camel-ftp](http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html) component.

My question is, how can I safely remove dependencies that may be runtime dependencies?

Comment: Use a system like ProGuard that analyzes dependencies on byte code level and throws out unused classes

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @SeanPatrickFloyd: it's a good one! ProGuard is going to take some time to learn and configure, especially for a big project. I'm not afraid of the work, but even aftewards I think I'd still like to clean-up my pom.xml files: I'd like to not include unused dependencies in the first place.

Comment: I understand, but that part is a lot harder. Perhaps you can use ProGuard for the analysis only and use the output to detect which dependencies you need to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel is dynamically instantiating classes and using interfaces, not concrete classes for things like camel-ftp. A byte code tool is of no use in analyzing dependencies in this case.

The solution is to have a comprehensive set of unit tests that cover your happy path and error path scenarios and test against a slimmed down set of declared Maven dependencies.

If you really want to trim dependencies, look to eliminate the use of *-spring components and use the blueprint or Java DSL. The Spring components tend to have a lot of transitive dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Matt! So `dependency:analyze` is probably returning a lot of false positives with respect to Camel, and ProGuard is unlikely to do better as it's also a bytecode tool. I wish I had a comprehensive unit test suite, but I won't be able to add one. I think I'll just turn my refactoring attention elsewhere.